# How to answer a question, if good answer would be a whole copy of a post from Drupal.org?

Tags: discussion, answers

So, there is [this little question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81030/output-themed-header-footer-to-a-custom-page-without-html-or-head-so-that-it). Answer to it is [here on Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1189732). This post is to short to make any excerpt from it, and copying it whole might be a copyright violation. Rewording it to obscure it's origin doesn't seems right either. So what's the best - fair and legal - way to provide an answer?

Comment: What makes you think it would be a copyright violation? Do Drupal.org have a non-permissive license for their website content? (I haven't ever checked)

Comment: @Clive it's CC share alike with parts under GPL, while SE is CC without share alike as far as I see, so it seems to me only SE to DO is OK. But I'm not a lawyer, I'll be glad to hear I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I can't comment on the legality either...but if there was a problem, surely it would've come up before now? Half or more of the questions/answers on DA contain code and literature copied verbatim from Drupal.org's documentation, issue queues, and handbooks. If this did turn out to be a legal issue we'd probably have to shut the site down! I can't see a problem with copy/pasting the solution, as long as its properly attributed

Comment: I guess for a definitive answer this should probably be asked in the [Legal group](https://groups.drupal.org/legal) on g.d.o

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, [the documentation](https://drupal.org/documentation) can be used under [Creative Commons License, Attribution-ShareAlike 2.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/), with PHP code under [GNU General License 2.0](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html), while posts on Stack Exchange are under [Creative Commons License, Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).
That is for the documentation; nothing is said for the forums.

As far as I can understand there isn't any copyright problem; as long as you give attribution to where you find the answer, there should not be any problem with reporting what you found in Drupal forum. Keep in mind that it is generally possible to expand the answer with something you personally write, and use the answer found on Drupal.org forum as guide.

As per code licensed under GPL, you can always show a quote of that code on Stack Exchange, as that falls under fair use. For what I understood, that includes also quoting a full Drupal function, since a single Drupal function is not the full Drupal code.